# Is there a way to confirm that jQuery is present on a webpage using Python/Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, selenium

We have a home grown automated test framework which utilizes Selenium Webdriver (written in Python). It uses a map to link the name of objects to it's identifier in the webpage. Unfortunately we seem to be running into an issue where we're not waiting long enough for AJAX calls to complete (there are some performance issues we're working through).

Now thanks to stackoverflow and other internet sources I've found the following segments of code:

*inserted into the framework just before the decision to interact with an object is made*

```
    try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ajax_complete, "Ajax check waited 5 seconds")
except TimeoutException:
    logger1.info("Warning: waited 5 seconds)
```

And then this is the code for ajax_complete:

```
def ajax_complete(driver):
try:
    return 0 == driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active")
except WebDriverException:
    pass
```

The problem is that some pages (a login screen) doesn't have jQuery present so I always fall into the TimeoutException. I know that at the moment the top segment of code will just timeout with a log message after 5 seconds but due to our performance issues I need to change that to 60 seconds. This means that the login page will have 3 minutes of wait time (1 min for entering of user name, 1 for password, and 1 to hit the login button) while waiting for the Ajax check to timeout because jQuery just isn't present on the page.

Is there something I can look for to confirm that jQuery actually exists on the webpage before doing the WebDriverWait check? Would doing some script element check be sufficient?

like:

```
if driver.find_element_by_tagname("<script>")
```

if that returns True then there's a script on the page - not necessarily jQuery, but it would be closer, maybe there's a more specific find_element_by that could be used. The hard part is that I'm trying to check for a negative (jQuery not present).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if `jQuery` "global" is defined with a script:

```
is_jquery_present = driver.execute_script("return (typeof jQuery != 'undefined');")
```

This though needs to be tested as it also takes time for a page to load jQuery itself.

Looking for a specific `script` may work for some pages but there is no guaranteed way of "importing" jquery library as, - for instance, at the very least, JS sources may be packed and minified.

Comment: That is an idea, I could wrap that like I'm wrapping the jQuery.active and just check for that first. And if it isn't found not bother to check if it is active. I'll give that a try

Comment: This worked!  Basically I just added an if statement that if true will check for ajax running 'if driver.execute_script("return (typeof jQuery != 'undefined');")' followed by the try block.  I am also going to try the suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

Optionally you could short-circuit your check.

```
return 0 == driver.execute_script("return (jQuery || {}).active")
```

If jQuest doesn't exist it will use an empty object, of which active will not be inside.

Or if you want it to be true if jQuery doesn't exist

```
return 0 == driver.execute_script("return (jQuery || { active: 0 }).active")
```

Comment: This worked as well, however the typeof jQuery suggestion being more explicit brought back a faster response. just making your short circuit ideas ended up waiting the full duration per object on the login page (3 minutes).

Comment: Weird, wonder why.  Did you do the first or second version?  If jQuery doesn't exist, the first one would always return false, while the second one would always return true.